# Float number formatting issue

Tags: java, numbers, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am using this code:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
float a=(float) 15000.345;
Sytem.out.println(df.format(a));
```

I am getting this output:`15,000.35`
I don't want comma to be come in this output.
My output should be:`15000.35`.

What is best way for getting this output in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
             DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
             df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
             df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
             df.setGroupingUsed(false);
             float a=(float) 15000.345;
             System.out.println(df.format(a));
```

and

```
 Sytem.out.println(df.format(a)); //wrong  //sytem

 System.out.println(df.format(a));//correct //System
```

Answer (score 5):

Read javadoc and use this:

`df.setGroupingUsed(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Grouping size should be set. The default value is 3. See the [Doc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setGroupingSize%28int%29)

```
df.setGroupingSize(0);
```

Or you use setGroupingUsed.

```
  df.setGroupingUsed(false);
```

Your Full code

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
df.setGroupingUsed(false);
float a=(float) 15000.345;
Sytem.out.println(df.format(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass `#####.##` as pattern

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#####.##");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatString, otherSymbols);
```

After that as you have done:

```
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
float a=(float) 15000.345;
System.out.println(df.format(a));
```

This will give you the intended result.